# select whole words after the selection in sublime text 2

Tags: text, find, sublimetext2

hi i want to select whole words after the selected word

```
232501149557
232506105112
232524426707
232526009612
232526012131
232526025811

232501149557
232506105112
232524426707
232526009612
232526012131
232526025811

232501149557
232506105112
232524426707
232526009612
232526012131
232526025811

232501149557
232506105112
232524426707
232526009612
232526012131
232526025811
```

[image]

as you can see i selected 8 line and it shows all same number for that word but i want to select 8 line and after the 8 lines words only..it means 8 line,15 line,22 lines not 1 line.
I don't know how to do it. could anybody tell me how to do it?

Comment: You can try to repeatedly use "Select next occurrence" from the menu or with the shortcut ctrl-d (I'm not on my pc so this can be mapped different)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to select all occurrences of a certain word except for the first occurrence?  I don't know of any way to do this directly but the PowerCursors package may be helpful. You could put your cursor on one of the words, press Alt+F3 to multi-select all matching words, then use PowerCursor to step through the selections and remove the ones you do not want selected. The package can be found here: https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PowerCursors

I hope that helps!